# What's the purpose of `sidt idtr` instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86

I encountered this instruction [here](http://phrack.org/issues/65/8.html). I think that I understand this incorrectly, because my understanding leads to believe that this instruction does absolutely nothing. Can you please point me to my mistake in understanding it?

`sidt` is supposed to ["store the contents of the global descriptor table register (GDTR) or the interrupt descriptor table register (IDTR) in the destination operand"](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/sidt.htm). But since the destination operand is `idtr` itself, it essentially means "store contents of `idtr` in `idtr`", so it would never actually do anything. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `idtr` there is not the idtr register, it's a variable in memory. You can not specify the idtr register as operand, it's implicit. So that instruction is reading the idtr register and placing it in a variable named idtr.

Comment: But I could specify another register as an operand, theoretically? If the variable has the same name as a register, how can I tell them apart?

Comment: _"If the variable has the same name as a register, how can I tell them apart?"_ If you're talking about doing something like `eax dd 0`, then presumably the assembler won't let you do that.

Comment: Incidentally, that's an advantage of at&t syntax, that it separates the registers and the symbols into different namespaces. Registers must be prefixed by a `%` and so you can do `mov %eax, eax` without any ambiguity (and without fear of colliding with future registers).

Comment: The potential for confusion and hard-to-catch bugs would be tremendous, though. Assembly is hard to follow as it is.